# how to implement if statements on radio button list?

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

i have an ecommerce site and in my order now page, i have 3 radio button lists namely: cash payment, payment gatewat and bank deposit. What i am planning to do is when you choose cash payment, it will direct you to a page for cash payment and when you go to payment gateway, it will direct you to another page and so on.

I know the code for it:

```
if
(rblPaymentMethod.SelectedItem.Value="1")
{
code here:
}
```

But having these codes, i am not sure where to put it.

```
protected void btnPlaceOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string productids = string.Empty;
        DataTable dt;
        if (Session["MyCart"] != null)
        {
            dt = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"];

            decimal totalPrice, totalProducts;
            bool totalPriceConversionResult = decimal.TryParse(txtTotalPrice.Text, out totalPrice), totalProductsConversionResult = decimal.TryParse(txtTotalProducts.Text, out totalProducts);


            ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart()
            {
                CustomerName = txtCustomerName.Text,
                CustomerEmailID = txtCustomerEmailID.Text,
                CustomerAddress = txtCustomerAddress.Text,
                CustomerPhoneNo = txtCustomerPhoneNo.Text,
                TotalProducts = totalProductsConversionResult ? Convert.ToInt32(totalProducts) : 0,
                TotalPrice = totalPriceConversionResult ? Convert.ToInt32(totalPrice) : 0,
                ProductList = productids,
                PaymentMethod = rblPaymentMethod.SelectedItem.Text

            };
            DataTable dtResult = k.SaveCustomerDetails();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) // loop on how many products are added by the user
            {
                ShoppingCart SaveProducts = new ShoppingCart()
                {
                    CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(dtResult.Rows[0][0]),
                    ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ProductID"]),
                    TotalProducts = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ProductQuantity"]),
                };
                SaveProducts.SaveCustomerProducts();
            }
            lblTransactionNo.Text = "Your Transaction Number: " + dtResult.Rows[0][0];

            pnlOrderPlaceSuccessfully.Visible = true;
            pnlCheckOut.Visible = false;
            pnlCategories.Visible = false;
            pnlMyCart.Visible = false;
            pnlEmptyCart.Visible = false;
            pnlProducts.Visible = false;

            SendOrderPlacedAlert(txtCustomerName.Text, txtCustomerEmailID.Text, Convert.ToString(dtResult.Rows[0][0]));


        }
    }
```

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your list items then add your if statements ...

here you get a code example

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem li in RadioButtonList1.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                Label1.Text = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue ;
            }
        }
    }
```

hope it can help you, do not forget to accept my answer as best :)